# Node cannot find node_modules in dockerized node app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker. I tried to dockerize my existing node application.
During docker-compose the app throws error stating it cannot find the node_modules.

Here's the error

```sh
dockerised-yelpcamp | > dockerised-yelpcamp@1.0.1 start /usr/src/app
dockerised-yelpcamp | > node app.js
dockerised-yelpcamp | 
dockerised-yelpcamp | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
dockerised-yelpcamp |     throw err;
dockerised-yelpcamp |     ^
dockerised-yelpcamp | 
dockerised-yelpcamp | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
dockerised-yelpcamp |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
dockerised-yelpcamp |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
dockerised-yelpcamp |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
dockerised-yelpcamp |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
dockerised-yelpcamp |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app.js:1:77)
.
.
.
dockerised-yelpcamp |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR! errno 1
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR! dockerised-yelpcamp@1.0.1 start: `node app.js`
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR! Exit status 1
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR! 
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR! Failed at the dockerised-yelpcamp@1.0.1 start script.
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
dockerised-yelpcamp | 
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-04-17T11_14_17_109Z-debug.log
dockerised-yelpcamp exited with code 1
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  main_app:
    container_name: dockerised-yelpcamp
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    links:
      - mongo
    volumes: ["./:/usr/src/app"]
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker file contains `npm install` which is executed successfully while building image.

Comment: your code is at root directory not at /usr/src/app . you have add code into /usr/src/app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `volumes:` directive is hiding everything the `Dockerfile` does with content from your local system.  If you don’t have a `node_modules` directory there or its architecture or library stack is incompatible with what’s in the container, this setup simply won’t work.

The common workaround seems to be to declare a second anonymous volume to hold `node_modules`, which will work until you change your `package.json` file.

My recommendation would be to remove the `volumes:` directive entirely.  Develop your application locally without Docker.  Once it works and you’ve tested it, use this `Dockerfile` to rebuild the image.  This both gives you a simpler non-Docker development setup, and replicates the environment you have in production (where you’re not going to copy the application code in addition to the Docker image that contains it).

Answer (score 0):

You copy only package.json, so you need node_modules folder created:

```
dockerised-yelpcamp | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

if my memory is good, docker container can't respond yes by default. So, he skip creation folder and node_modules stay missing.